# Turning multiple dictionary values into single output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I saw similar questions/answers but didn't find an appropriate example to follow. I have a list (of a list) of dictionaries like the following:

```
list_of_dictionaries = [
    [{'key1': {'subkey1': 1.0},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.0},'key3': 'abc'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 1.1},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.1},'key3': 'def'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 1.2},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.2},'key3': 'ghi'},
     {'key5': 5.0, 'key6': 6.0}],
    [{'key1': {'subkey1': 2.0},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.0},'key3': 'abc'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 2.1},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.1},'key3': 'def'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 2.2},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.2},'key3': 'ghi'},
     {'key5': 7.0, 'key6': 8.0}]
]
```

The challenging part is I'd like to have a single output for each of the first 3 dictionaries that pairs the 4th element of each list:

```
#desired output
List1 - Subkey1 value: 1.0 /// Subkey2 value: 1.0 /// Key3 value: abc /// Key5 value: 5.0 /// Key6 value: 6.0
List1 - Subkey1 value: 1.1 /// Subkey2 value: 1.1 /// Key3 value: def /// Key5 value: 5.0 /// Key6 value: 6.0
List1 - Subkey1 value: 1.2 /// Subkey2 value: 1.2 /// Key3 value: ghi /// Key5 value: 5.0 /// Key6 value: 6.0
List2 - Subkey1 value: 2.0 /// Subkey2 value: 2.0 /// Key3 value: abc /// Key5 value: 7.0 /// Key6 value: 8.0
List2 - Subkey1 value: 2.1 /// Subkey2 value: 2.1 /// Key3 value: def /// Key5 value: 7.0 /// Key6 value: 8.0
List2 - Subkey1 value: 2.2 /// Subkey2 value: 2.2 /// Key3 value: ghi /// Key5 value: 7.0 /// Key6 value: 8.0
```

Tried the following which is close but I'm stumped on how to only join key5 and key6 values to each corresponding print statements:

```
for list_of_metrics in list_of_dictionaries:  
    for dictionary in list_of_metrics:
        if 'key1' in dictionary:
            subkey1 = dictionary['key1']['subkey1']
            print('Key1, Subkey1 value: ' + str(subkey1))
        if 'key5' in dictionary:
            key5 = dictionary['key5']
            key6 = dictionary['key6']
            print('Key5 value: ' + str(key5) + ', Key6 value: ' + str(key6))

#output
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.1
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.2
Key5 value: 5.0, Key6 value: 6.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.1
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.2
Key5 value: 7.0, Key6 value: 8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to go with slicing here and then separately iterate over the last dictionary since you need to accumulate it with all the other elements of the inner list.

```
for list_of_metrics in list_of_dictionaries:
    for d in list_of_metrics[:3]:
        result = ""
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for k, v in value.items():
                    result += f"{k} : {v} " 
            else:
                result += f"{key}: {value} "

        for key, value in list_of_metrics[3].items():
                result += f"{key} : {value} "

        print(result)
    print()
```

Output:

```
subkey1 : 1.0 subkey2 : 1.0 key3: abc key5 : 5.0 key6 : 6.0 
subkey1 : 1.1 subkey2 : 1.1 key3: def key5 : 5.0 key6 : 6.0 
subkey1 : 1.2 subkey2 : 1.2 key3: ghi key5 : 5.0 key6 : 6.0 

subkey1 : 2.0 subkey2 : 2.0 key3: abc key5 : 7.0 key6 : 8.0 
subkey1 : 2.1 subkey2 : 2.1 key3: def key5 : 7.0 key6 : 8.0 
subkey1 : 2.2 subkey2 : 2.2 key3: ghi key5 : 7.0 key6 : 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [update function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) with slicing. See below:

```
>>> for lod in list_of_lod:
...     for each_d in lod[:-1]:
...             each_d.update(lod[-1])
...     lod.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where key5 and key6 are located, but you want to add them to all the other dictionaries, you could do something like this:

```py
list_of_dictionaries = [
    [{'key1': {'subkey1': 1.0},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.0},'key3': 'abc'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 1.1},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.1},'key3': 'def'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 1.2},'key2': {'subkey2': 1.2},'key3': 'ghi'},
     {'key5': 5.0, 'key6': 6.0}],
    [{'key1': {'subkey1': 2.0},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.0},'key3': 'abc'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 2.1},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.1},'key3': 'def'},
     {'key1': {'subkey1': 2.2},'key2': {'subkey2': 2.2},'key3': 'ghi'},
     {'key5': 7.0, 'key6': 8.0}]
]

for list_of_metrics in list_of_dictionaries:
    extra = next((d for d in list_of_metrics if 'key5' in d), None)
    print('extra', extra)
    for dictionary in list_of_metrics:
        if 'key1' in dictionary:
            subkey1 = dictionary['key1']['subkey1']
            print('Key1, Subkey1 value:', subkey1, 'Key5 value:', extra['key5'], 'Key6 value:', extra['key6'])
```

You'll get something like the following output:

```
extra {'key5': 5.0, 'key6': 6.0}
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.0 Key5 value: 5.0 Key6 value: 6.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.1 Key5 value: 5.0 Key6 value: 6.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 1.2 Key5 value: 5.0 Key6 value: 6.0
extra {'key5': 7.0, 'key6': 8.0}
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.0 Key5 value: 7.0 Key6 value: 8.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.1 Key5 value: 7.0 Key6 value: 8.0
Key1, Subkey1 value: 2.2 Key5 value: 7.0 Key6 value: 8.0
```